# Library to implement Windows Explorer icon overlays

Tags: windows, open-source, library, c#, shell-extension

I want to develop a tool to show icon overlays in Windows Explorer.
Similar to what Dropbox or TortoiseGit do, example:

[image: icon overlays]

What library would make this as easy and reliable as possible?

Requirements:

- Open source (compatible with GNU-GPLv3)
- Reliability is the most important, more important than the language
- Ideally C#, or something that can load and call a C# DLL
- I would prefer to avoid forcing users to install extra software such as a JRE, if possible
- Works with Windows 7+

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the Overlay Server from [TortoiseHG](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/):

- it is Open Source, GPL2, and as far as I know does not rely on any none free software tools
- implemented in a single file, [TortoiseHgOverlayServer.py](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/src), of, *at the moment*, 553 lines including comments & blank lines.
- Works with Windows XP through 10.
- Very reliable but subject to the limitation that all such windows tools face that there are a limited number of overly IDs available in Windows so the various overlay servers compete for the use of them.
- Implemented in python so easy to read and uses free tools.
- You could port it to [IronPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IronPython) to use it from within your C# code.

[image: Tortoise icon overlay]

Comment: The homepage says "*Acknowledgement: The TortoiseHg installer for Windows includes the TortoiseOverlays handler, as provided by the TortoiseSVN project.*" so maybe I should work from that instead? Or has TortoiseHG improved on it?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - Well spotted - I am not sure if that is current and the  TortoiseHgOverlayServer.py has been superseded or if he comment little out of date.

Answer (score 1):

[Liferay Nativity](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-nativity) is a cross-platform library for adding icon overlays and context menus to file browsers.

- Open source: Yes, LGPL
- Reliable: It is used in a commercially-supported product, so I guess, but not tested
- Communication is made via JSON/sockets, so it can presumably talk with C# after a bit of development on the C# side
- **Unfortunately seems to require a JRE**
- Works with Windows Vista+, and even Mac OS X 10.7+ and Linux GNOME Nautilus 3.x

[image: Liferay Sync icon overlay]

Answer (score 1):

OwnCloud seems to have made their own implementation of icon overlays. It is [available since 1.7.0](https://dragotin.wordpress.com/2014/11/08/owncloud-client-1-7-0-released/).

License: GNU-LGPL
Source: https://github.com/owncloud/client/tree/master/shell_integration
Info: https://github.com/owncloud/client/wiki/Debugging-Overlay-Icons

The technical details of implementation are explained at https://github.com/owncloud/client/wiki/Overlay-Icons

Answer (score 0):

[SharpShell](https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell) sounds like the perfect solution: Implement an easy C# interface, and SharpShell does all of the dark C stuff.

License: MIT
Source code: https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell
Tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/545781/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Icon-Overlay-Handlers

Unfortunately, even after having spent weeks developing with its icon overlay part the result is still not reliable (sometimes the overlay icons don't show up), and it [has](https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell/issues/103) [bugs](https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell/issues/92). It is a unfortunate as other parts of SharpShell (like shell context menus) work very well.

[image: SharpShell icon overlay]

Comment: Will it work with windows folders too?

Comment: @shiv.mymail Good question, I don't know.